# $\chi(G) + \chi(G') \leq n+1$ - Trouble understanding the proof of one of the Nordhaus-Gaddum Inequalities

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am reading through the article [On Complementary Graphs](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2306658) by E. A. Nordhaus and J. W. Gaddum which lays out the proof of the following inequality, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the simple graph $G$ and its complement $G'$.

$$\chi(G) + \chi(G') \leq n+1$$

First of all it uses $k$ and $k'$ for $\chi(G)$ and $\chi(G')$ respectively

It does so via induction, when $n=1$, the inequality obviously holds, it then assumes that $$k + k' \leq n+1$$

The article then asks us to consider an additional vertex $P$ which has $q$ edges connected to the vertices of $G$ and $n-q$ vertices connected to the vertices of $\overline{G}$, which means that the chromatic numbers of $H = G + P$ and $H' = G'+P$  are $l$ and $l'$ respectively

It is clear that the chromatic number of G can at most be increased by 1 by the addition of a node, so $l \leq k+1$, similarly $l' \leq k' + 1$.

Now consider the case when $l \leq k$ or $l' \leq k'$, in this case $$l+l' \leq k+k' + 1$$ however we assumed that $k + k' \leq n+1$ and so this becomes $$l+l' \leq (n+1) + 1$$

**This is where I struggle** - I am having trouble with the case where $l = k+1$ and $l' = k' + 1$. The article states that in this case $q \geq k$ and $n-q \geq k'$, which would mean $k+k' \leq n$ which means $l+l' \leq k+k' + 2 = n+2 = (n+1) + 1$ which completes the induction.

Can anyone give any ideas why:

($l = k+1$ and $l' = k' + 1$) $\implies$ ($q \geq k$ and $n-q \geq k'$)

Comment: The reason $l=k+1\implies q\ge k$ is that, if the original graph $G$ is colored with $k$ colors, and if the new vertex $P$ did **not** have neighbors of every color, then $P$ could be colored with one of the old colors, making $l=k$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a graph $G$ with $\chi(G)+\chi(G')\le n(G)+1$. When we add a new vertex $v$ to $G$, $n(G+v)=n(G)+1$. Since $\chi(G+v)\le\chi(G)+1$ and $\chi(G'+v)\le\chi(G')+1$,, everything is fine unless $\chi(G+v)\gt\chi(G)$ **and** $\chi(G'+v)\gt\chi(G')$. For that to happen, the new vertex $v$ would have to have at least $\chi(G)$ neighbors in $G$ (at least one of each color), and at least $\chi(G')$ neighbors in $G'$. In that case $\chi(G)+\chi(G')\le n(G)$, and $\chi(G+v)+\chi(G'+v)=\chi(G)+1+\chi(G')+1\le n(G)+2=n(G+v)+1$, Q.E.D.